# How to update image with AJAX in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

I'm having problems updating a record with an image. I don't what I need to do. My image is stored in a public folder called 'img/products'

***ProductController.php***

This is my controller. It works well without modifying the image.

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->input(), array(
            'name' => 'required',
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'price_neto' => 'required',
            'iva' => 'required',
            'price_total' => 'required',
            'image' => '',
        ));

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'error'    => true,
                'messages' => $validator->errors(),
            ], 422);
        }

        $products = Product::find($id);

        $products->name = $request->input('name');
        $products->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
        $products->description = $request->input('description');
        $products->price_neto = $request->input('price_neto');
        $products->iva = $request->input('iva');
        $products->price_total = $request->input('price_total');
        $products->image = $request->input('image');

        $products->save();

        return response()->json([
            'error' => false,
            'products'  => $products,
        ], 200);
    }
```

***Product.js***

All I know is that I have to use `var formData = new FormData ($ ("# frmAddProduct") [0]);` as in the store function. I can enter records with images but not edit them. My image is stored in a public folder called 'img/products'

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btn-edit").click(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: '/product/' + $("#frmEditProduct input[name=product_id]").val(),
            data: {
                name: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=name]").val(),
                category_id: $("#frmEditProduct select[name=category_id]").val(),
                description: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=description]").val(),
                price_neto: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=price_neto2]").val(),
                iva: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=iva2]").val(),
                price_total: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=price_total2]").val(),
                image: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=image]").val(),
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#frmEditProduct').trigger("reset");
                $("#frmEditProduct .close").click();
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error: function(data) {
                var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                $('#edit-product-errors').html('');
                $.each(errors.messages, function(key, value) {
                    $('#edit-product-errors').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
                });
                $("#edit-error-bag").show();
            }
        });
    });

});

function editProductForm(product_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/product/' + product_id,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#edit-error-bag").hide();
            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=name]").val(data.products.name);
            $("#frmEditProduct select[name=category_id]").val(data.products.category_id);
            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=description]").val(data.products.description);
            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=price_neto2]").val(data.products.price_neto);
            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=iva2]").val(data.products.iva);
            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=price_total2]").val(data.products.price_total);
            $("#frmEditProduct file[name=image]").val(data.products.image);
            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=product_id]").val(data.products.id);
            $('#editProductModal').modal('show');
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you created links to the storage path?    php artisan storage:link

Comment: No, I have not.  I have not used that command and I already have the store and delete functions working. @AlexandreBarbosa

Comment: OK, although I responded with an update method as an example, I'm not so sure if I understand your situation. Because I would like to know where you are storing your images to get them. If you are storing in the "storage" folder, you must create links to the storage. But if you are storing images in the public folder as other "assets," the solution will be different.

Comment: The image is stored in the public folder ('image/products/') @AlexandreBarbosa

Comment: Please, look at the end of my answer, to see if it can help you as you need. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the file exists before trying to delete, for example:

```
 $product = Product::find($id);

 if(!$product)
 {
     return response()->json(['error' => 'Product not found'], 404);
 }

 if (Storage::disk('local')->exists('img/products/'.$product->image)) {
    Storage::disk('local')->delete('img/products/'.$product->image);
 }
```

Take a look one example only:

```
public function update(UpdateProductFormRequest $request, $id)
{
     $product = Product::find($id); 

     $data = $request->only('name','category_id','description',
                               'price_neto','iva','price_total');

     if(!$product)
     {
         return response()->json(['error' => 'Product not found'], 404);
     }

     // when saving the file, delete the old file first
     if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

        $file              = $request->file('image');

        $original_filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        // $mime           = $file->getMimeType();  // Suggestion
        $extention         = $file->getExtension();
        // $size           = $file->getClientSize(); // Suggestion

        $stored_filename   = $original_filename; // md5($original_filename); // Suggestion 
        $file_path         = storage_path('public/img/products/');


        if (Storage::disk('local')
                  ->exists("public/img/products/{$stored_filename}.{$extention}")) 
        {
            Storage::disk('local')
                  ->delete("public/img/products/{$recordSet->stored_filename}.{$extention}");
        } 
        $file_moved = $file->move($file_path, "{$stored_filename}.{$extention}");
        $data->image = "{$stored_filename}.{$extention}";
     }

     // Updating data    
     $result = $product->update($data);

     if ($result) {
        /* return redirect()
                ->route('products.index')
                ->withSuccess('Product was successfully updated'); */

         return response()->json([
              'message' => 'Product was successfully updated'
              'product' => $product
         ]); // You don't have to put 200 because it's the default
     }


     /* return back()
        ->withErrors(['Unable to update the product'])
        ->withInput($request->input()); */

     return response()->json(['error' => 'Unable to update the product'], 400);
}
```

It would be better if you create a form request to do your validations.

Don't forget to create links to the storage path:

```
 php artisan storage:link
```

I think it would be helpful:

```
 $("#btn-edit").click(function() {

    var formData = new FormData($("#frmAddProduct")[0]);
    formData.append('_method', 'put');
    formData.append('_token', "{{ csrf_token() }}"); // if you are using Blade

    var route= "{{ route('products.update', ['id' => ':id']) }}"; // if you are using Blade
    route= route.replace(':id', $("#frmEditProduct input[name=product_id]").val())

    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: route,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#frmEditProduct').trigger("reset");
            $("#frmEditProduct .close").click();
            window.location.reload();
        },
        error: function(data) {
            var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
            $('#edit-product-errors').html('');
            $.each(errors.messages, function(key, value) {
                $('#edit-product-errors').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
            });
            $("#edit-error-bag").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Is your js script in "Blade" ? If so, try it this way:

```
var image = '{{ asset("/img/products/_image_file") }}'

image.replace('_image_file', data.products.image)

$("#frmEditProduct file[name=image]").val(image)
```

Note that we can first use the "asset ()" helper to create the full path to use to find the image, but with a "_image_file" placeholder
After that, we use the replace ()  function to change the "_image_file" placeholder with the actual image file brought from the ajax response.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the post! Change from "store" method to "update" method!

Comment: How should I do if the image is stored in the public folder?

Comment: you can use `asset()` method

Comment: Yes, as @jigs_ responded, you can use the asset() helper in Blade, as follows: <img src='{{ asset("/img/public/{$product->image}") }}" />

Comment: Is your script in "Blade" ? If so, try it this way: 

var image = '{{ asset("/img/products/_image_file") }}'
image.replace('_image_file', data.products.image)
$("#frmEditProduct file[name=image]").val(data.products.image)

Comment: I will edit my answer because my comment was bad here

Comment: Something like this? @AlexandreBarbosa

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

**ProductController.php**

```html
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->input(), array(
            'name' => 'required',
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'price_neto' => 'required',
            'iva' => 'required',
            'price_total' => 'required',
            'image' => '',
        ));

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'error'    => true,
                'messages' => $validator->errors(),
            ], 422);
        }

        $products = Product::find($id);

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

            $productImage = $request->file('image');           
            $productImageName = rand() . '.' . $productImage->getClientOriginalExtension();

            if (Storage::disk('local')->exists("img/products/{$productImageName}")) {
                Storage::disk('local')->delete("img/products/{$recordSet->$productImageName}");
            }

            $file_moved  = $productImage->move(public_path('img/products'), $productImageName);
            $data->image = "{$productImageName}";
        }

        $products->save([
            'name'          => $request->name,
            'category_id'   => $request->category_id,
            'description'   => $request->description,
            'price_neto'    => $request->price_neto,
            'iva'           => $request->iva,
            'price_total'   => $request->price_total,
            'image'         => $productImageName,
        ]);

        return response()->json([
            'error' => false,
            'products'  => $products,
        ]);

    }
```

**Product.js**

```js
$("#btn-edit").click(function() {

        var formData = new FormData($("#frmEditProduct")[0]);
        formData.append('_method', 'put');

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/product/' + $("#frmEditProduct input[name=product_id]").val(),
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#frmEditProduct').trigger("reset");
                $("#frmEditProduct .close").click();
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error: function(data) {
                var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                $('#edit-product-errors').html('');
                $.each(errors.messages, function(key, value) {
                    $('#edit-product-errors').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
                });
                $("#edit-error-bag").show();
            }
        });
    });
```